# MS Access Runtime 2007 - Closes with no error, requires reinstall

Tags: windows, microsoft-access

I have a little program developed in access 2007, it connects to a MySQL DB via ODBC connector.

The following problem does not happen in all PCs, it doesn't even happen in all of the same WinOS that the multiple clients use.

The user will input its user/pass and then hit login on a form, the program will begin validations and at the same point, where it has to validate access to the department the program will suddenly close.

And it will keep doing that, at the same spot, every time, unless the MS Access Runtime is reinstalled.

As I stated before, I don't understand why it happens, since it doesn't happen to everyone, and some machines that didn't have the issue will suddenly start doing it, and its not even every time or day, its almost random on the PCs that do it.

It only happens with Win8 and up, but not all Win8+ do it...

Any ideas on what could it be?

Edit (more info):
32 bit software yes, MSAccess Runtime 12.0.6425.1000

Comment: Try to find what is different about the computers where the problem happens, as regarding Windows version and installed apps. Try to find some information in the Event Viewer and look in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps` for `.dmp` files for this application; if found you may zip and upload a couple for analysis. Questions: Which Access Runtime? I suppose you're using 32-bit software.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I added that info to the main question. And will try to look for the crashdumps you mentioned an return with the information, thank you.